# verificar opciones de fecha y hora automática en Swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone, swift4

la idea es poder agregar un if que restringa el uso de la aplicación si la opción de fecha y hora no este automática en el iPhone, e buscado y solo encuentro el típico código el cual utiliza el data del teléfono..

```
                // obtencion de fecha
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                //dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Santiago")
                let date = Date()
                let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

                // obtencion de hora
                let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
                timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                //timeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Santiago")
                let timeString = "\(timeFormatter.string(from: Date()))"
```

lo intente mediante un GET a una api y funciona perfecto con el timeStamp el tema hay es y si no hay conexión a internet? por ende mi necesidad de restringir eso... de antemano gracias

Comment: En vista de busque durante largo tiempo y encontre la solucion.....en los sistemas IOS no se permite ingresar a opciones de modificacion a tal nivel, por tanto es inviable y solo queda esperar que el usuario final no altere deliberadamente la hora y/o fecha ya que ninguna aplicacion podra manejar  o darse cuenta de ese cambio de forma offline.

Answer (score -1):

//Para el modo Online, lo que utilize fue una API(Timezonedb) para obtener la Fecha y hora.

```
static func obtenerFechayHoraPorGPS(latitud: String, logintud: String,success:@escaping (_ response: String)->(), failure:@escaping (_ response: Response)->()){
    let getTimezonedb = ATNetworkConstants.timezonedb + "position&lat=\(latitud)&by=position&lng=\(logintud)"
        Alamofire.request(getTimezonedb).responseJSON {
            response in
            let _response = Response()
            if (response.result.error != nil || response.response?.statusCode != 200){
            _response.status = .failure
            _response.error = response.result.error as NSError?
            failure(_response)
            } else {

                _response.status = .success
                _response.object = response.result.value as AnyObject?
                success(_response.object!["formatted"] as? String ?? "")
                }
        }
}
```